# I have a problem with instantiate direction and offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an 8 direction 2D character and he fires a projectile at mouse position.
I want to fire that projectile at mouse position, but having offset on y axis on the starting point. 
It would be easy if i could just work around that with sprite pivot or something, but unfortunately i can't afford doing so and need to fix that in another way.
Check Image on link

(A) To do that i used this code, and since the pivot of the object is around his legs it behaves like in the image.

```
Vector3 MousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
Vector2 direction = (Vector2)((MousePos - transform.position));
direction.Normalize();

GameObject bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate(
    bullet1,
    new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z) + (Vector3)((direction) * 0.05f),
    Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, shootRotation));
```

i'm moving that instantiated object with

```
bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * speed
```

But that's not working as i wish, because the projectile is firing from character belt.

(B) so i tried adding a +0.35f to transform.position.y and it worked for a while, until i noticed that the offset was affecting the landing point aswell, so it dosen't really shoot at the real mouse position

[image]

Comment: and where does `shootRotation` come from?

Comment: from another method, but dosen't really matter to my problem i guess, i just need it to set the object in the correct rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can drastically reduce your code. There are some unnecessary typecasts and Vector creations.

To B)

As you calculate the direction depending on `transform.position` but later instantiate the bullet using `transform.position + Vector3.up * 0.35f` this offset value is also used for the direction so it seems that your target position is shifted up by the same amount.

Instead calculate a `bulletOrigin` value first adding whatever spawn offset and then calculate the `direction` according to this `bulletOrigin` instead of using `transform.position`.

```
// Instead of new Vector3(transfor.position.x, transform.position,y, transform.position.z)
// you can simply use transform.position
// Vector3 (and Vector2) is a struct -> value type
// a new Vector is created anyway by assigning it
var bulletOrigin = transfor.position /* + additionalOffsetVector */;
// add the offset here already so the direction is later calculated between
// the correct positions

var mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
// Vector3 and Vector2 are implicitely casted between each other
// You don't have to typecast everytime
var direction = (mousePos - bulletOrigin).normalized;

bulletOrigin += 0.05f * direction;

// You didn't tell us where shootRotation comes from but in general
// I would rather use this for the rotation so it simply faces with the forward
// vector in the direction
var bulletRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction, Vector3.forward);

var bullet = Instantiate(bullet1, bulletOrigin, bulletRotation);
// Latest here the direction is automatically used as Vector2
bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * speed;
```

also see [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html)

---

Some notes regarding performance:

- If you rather make the prefab field of type

  ```
  public Rigidbody2D bullet1;
  ```

  then you can skip the `GetComponent` call later and simply use

  ```
  var bullet = Instantiate(bullet1, bulletOrigin, bulletRotation);
  bullet.velocity = direction * speed;
  ```
- `Camera.main` is quite expensive and you should do it only once and store the reference. Either already via the Inspector

  ```
  [SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;
  ```

  setting it in `Awake` at gamestart

  ```
  private void Awake()
  {
      if(!mainCamera) mainCamera = Camera.main;
  }
  ```

  or as very last resort in cases where you instantiate different cameras (which is actually almost never the case ;) ) directly in your method

  ```
  if(!mainCamera) mainCamera = Camera.main;
  var MousePos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working as intended now :)

And thx for the tips on formatting